# How to correctly train my Neural Network

Tags: javascript, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to teach a neural network to decide where to go based on its inputted *life level*. The neural network will always receive three inputs `[x, y, life]`. If `life => 0.2`, it should output the angle from `[x, y]` to `(1, 1)`. If `life < 0.2`, it should output the angle from `[x, y]` to `(0, 0)`.

As the inputs and outputs of neurons should be between `0` and `1`, I divide the angle by `2 *Math.PI`.

Here is the code:

```
var network = new synaptic.Architect.Perceptron(3,4,1);

for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
  var x = Math.random();
  var y = Math.random();
  var angle1 = angleToPoint(x, y, 0, 0) / (2 * Math.PI);
  var angle2 = angleToPoint(x, y, 1, 1) / (2 * Math.PI);
  for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    network.activate([x,y,j/100]);
    if(j < 20){
      network.propagate(0.3, [angle1]);
    } else {
      network.propagate(0.3, [angle2]);
    }
  }
}
```

> Try it out here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/hekqj5jq/)

So when I enter the following input `[0, 1, 0.19]`, I expect the neural network to output something close to `[0.75]` (`1.5PI / 2PI`). But my results are completely inconsistent and show no correlation with any input given at all.

What mistake am I making in teaching my Neural network?

> I have managed to teach a neural network to output `1` when input `[a, b, c]` with `c => 0.2` and `0` when input `[a, b, c]` with `c < 0.2`. I have also managed to teach it to output an angle to a certain location based on `[x, y]` input, however **I can't seem to combine them**.

---

As requested, I have written some code that uses 2 Neural Networks to get the desired output. The first neural network converts life level to a 0 or a 1, and the second neural network outputs an angle depending on the 0 or 1 it got outputted from the first neural network. This is the code:

```
// This network outputs 1 when life => 0.2, otherwise 0
var network1 = new synaptic.Architect.Perceptron(3,3,1);
// This network outputs the angle to a certain point based on life
var network2 = new synaptic.Architect.Perceptron(3,3,1);

for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
  var x = Math.random();
  var y = Math.random();
  var angle1 = angleToPoint(x, y, 0, 0) / (2 * Math.PI);
  var angle2 = angleToPoint(x, y, 1, 1) / (2 * Math.PI);

  for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    network1.activate([x,y,j/100]);
    if(j < 20){
      network1.propagate(0.1, [0]);
    } else {
      network1.propagate(0.1, [1]);
    }
     network2.activate([x,y,0]);
    network2.propagate(0.1, [angle1]);
    network2.activate([x,y,1]);
    network2.propagate(0.1, [angle2]);
  }
}
```

> Try it out here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wagenaartje/0zz4aea3/)

As you can see in this example. It manages to reach the desired output quite closely, by adding more iterations it will come even closer.

Comment: I suggest adding more neurons to hidden layer.

Comment: @cdm I tried, but did not make a difference. I'm trying to make my own network now by configuring individual layers.

Comment: either there is a problems with your layers, or using multiple neural network is a better solution.

Comment: @Walfrat hmm seems to be the only solution. Ill try projecting networks to each other.

Comment: Otherwise you can check if your javascript library provide somthing else than neural network, for a result of type 0/1, a support vector machine (SVM) is way lighter than a neural network.

Comment: What is `angleToPoint`?

Comment: @Richard I had it in the question earlier, but I'm almost certain that the mistake doens't lie there as I am able to do the job with 2 seperate neural networks. Check out the function at the jsfiddle link!

Comment: @ThomasW: Questions on SO should, as much as feasible, contain MWEs (minimum working examples) for the code which demonstrate the problems to be solved. This makes for quick reads and prevents important elements of a question from being lost when external links die. I'm happy to try my hand at solving your question, but won't do it through jsFiddle.

Comment: I'd recommend that you change your training set. It is unbalanced and biased towards `life > 0.2`. Probably randomizing it also helps, because if you train sequentially your network ends up forgetting the initial inputs.

Comment: It would also be easier for everybody else if you shared both your networks that work on the lesser tasks you said you solved.

Comment: @ThomasW btw, "angle to (0,0)" is not defined. Did you mean "angle to (1,0)" as the angle to the `x` axis?

Comment: @VillasV I have updated my post with a working example that uses 2 Neural Networks. I don't completely understand your comment about the angles, could you explain a little more? Angle to (0,0) is just the angle from the inputted (x,y) to (0,0) calculated by angleToPoint.

Comment: @Richard thank you for the feedback. I have added an MWE.

Comment: But there's no such thing as "angle to (0,0)". That function returns something, yes, but it can't mean what you describe. It returns the angle between (p1-p2) and the `x` axis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134898/discussion-between-villasv-and-thomas-w).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Observations

1. Skewed Distribution sampled as Training set

   Your training set is choosing the `life` parameter inside `for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++)`, which is highly biased towards `j>20` and consequently `life>0.2`. It has 4 times more training data for that subset, which makes your training function prioritize.
2. Non-shuffled training data

   You are training sequentially against the `life` parameter, which can be harmful. You network will end up giving more attention to the bigger `j`s since it's the most recent reason for network propagations. You should shuffle your training set to avoid this bias.

   *This will stack with the previous point, because you're again giving more attention to some subset of `life` values.*
3. You should measure your training performance as well

   Your network, despite previous observations, was not really that bad. Your training error was not as huge as your tests. This discrepancy usually means that you're training and testing on different sample distributions.

   You could say that you have two classes of data points: the ones with `life>0.2` and the others not. But because you introduced a discontinuity in the `angleToPoint` function, I'd recommend that you separate in three classes: keep a class for `life<0.2` (because the function behaves continuously) and split `life>0.2` in "above (1,1)" and "below (1,1)."
4. Network complexity

   You could successfully train a network for each task separately. Now you want to **stack** them. This is quite the purpose of *deep* learning: each layer builds on the concepts perceived by the previous layer, therefore increasing the complexity of the concepts it can learn.

   So instead of using 20 nodes in a single layer, I'd recommend that you use 2 layers of 10 nodes. This matches the classes hierarchy I mentioned in the previous point.

## The Code

Running this code I had a training/testing error of `0.0004`/`0.0002`.

> https://jsfiddle.net/hekqj5jq/11/

```
var network = new synaptic.Architect.Perceptron(3,10,10,1);
var trainer = new synaptic.Trainer(network);
var trainingSet = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
  // 1st category: above vector (1,1), measure against (1,1)
  var x = getRandom(0.0, 1.0);
  var y = getRandom(x, 1.0);
  var z = getRandom(0.2, 1);
  var angle = angleToPoint(x, y, 1, 1) / (2 * Math.PI);
  trainingSet.push({input: [x,y,z], output: [angle]});
  // 2nd category: below vector (1,1), measure against (1,1)
  var x = getRandom(0.0, 1.0);
  var y = getRandom(0.0, x);
  var z = getRandom(0.2, 1);
  var angle = angleToPoint(x, y, 1, 1) / (2 * Math.PI);
  trainingSet.push({input: [x,y,z], output: [angle]});
  // 3rd category: above/below vector (1,1), measure against (0,0)
  var x = getRandom(0.0, 1.0);
  var y = getRandom(0.0, 1.0);
  var z = getRandom(0.0, 0.2);
  var angle = angleToPoint(x, y, 0, 0) / (2 * Math.PI);
  trainingSet.push({input: [x,y,z], output: [angle]});
}

trainer.train(trainingSet, {
    rate: 0.1,
    error: 0.0001,
    iterations: 50,
    shuffle: true,
    log: 1,
    cost: synaptic.Trainer.cost.MSE
});

testSet = [
    {input: [0,1,0.25], output: [angleToPoint(0, 1, 1, 1) / (2 * Math.PI)]},
    {input: [1,0,0.35], output: [angleToPoint(1, 0, 1, 1) / (2 * Math.PI)]},
    {input: [0,1,0.10], output: [angleToPoint(0, 1, 0, 0) / (2 * Math.PI)]},
    {input: [1,0,0.15], output: [angleToPoint(1, 0, 0, 0) / (2 * Math.PI)]}
];

$('html').append('<p>Train:</p> ' + JSON.stringify(trainer.test(trainingSet)));
$('html').append('<p>Tests:</p> ' + JSON.stringify(trainer.test(testSet)));

$('html').append('<p>1st:</p> ')
$('html').append('<p>Expect:</p> ' + angleToPoint(0, 1, 1, 1) / (2 * Math.PI));
$('html').append('<p>Received: </p> ' + network.activate([0, 1, 0.25]));

$('html').append('<p>2nd:</p> ')
$('html').append('<p>Expect:</p> ' + angleToPoint(1, 0, 1, 1) / (2 * Math.PI));
$('html').append('<p>Received: </p> ' + network.activate([1, 0, 0.25]));

$('html').append('<p>3rd:</p> ')
$('html').append('<p>Expect:</p> ' + angleToPoint(0, 1, 0, 0) / (2 * Math.PI));
$('html').append('<p>Received: </p> ' + network.activate([0, 1, 0.15]));

$('html').append('<p>4th:</p> ')
$('html').append('<p>Expect:</p> ' + angleToPoint(1, 0, 0, 0) / (2 * Math.PI));
$('html').append('<p>Received: </p> ' + network.activate([1, 0, 0.15]));

function angleToPoint(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
  if(angle < 0){
    angle += 2 * Math.PI;
  }
  return angle;
}

function getRandom (min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

## Further Remarks

As I mentioned in the comments and in the chat, there's no such a thing as "angle between (x,y) and (0,0)", because the notion of angle between vectors is usually taken as the difference between their directions and `(0,0)` has no direction.

Your function `angleToPoint(p1, p2)` returns instead the direction of (p1-p2). For p2 = `(0,0)`, that means the angle between p1 and the `x` axis alright. But for p1=`(1,1)` and p2=`(1,0)` it will not return 45 degrees. For p1=p2, it's undefined instead of zero.

Comment: btw, I think this should be moved to the Cross Validated network, and there you might get even better answers and a few corrections to my analysis.